# Naming batch file Gradle's application plugin

Tags: gradle

I would like to give a custom file name to my batch file inside the archive/distribution when using Gradle's application plugin. 
Following is the build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.org.test.TestMain';

dependencies {
 compile group: 'com.oracle', name: 'ojdbc7', version: '+'
}
```

[image: See this picture]

I would like to rename **test.bat** to **abc_xyz.bat**. in the distribution.
Can anyone suggest how this can be possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
createStartScripts {
    applicationName = 'abc_xyz'
}
```

Not tested it though...

Comment: With Gradle 3.x and later, the task is now called `startScripts`, not `createStartScripts`. https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html Also, it doesn't really give the desired control, for example, I wanted to rename the script as `startup.sh`, but changing the application name only creates a script `startup`. I can rename it but that seems more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Kotlin DSL

```
tasks.withType<CreateStartScripts> {
    applicationName = "blah"
}
```

would create `blah` and `blah.bat`. Verified with Gradle 6.6.1.